# Where is the audio device in Ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, ffmpeg, capture

For most devices there's a raw version in `/dev`.

For the video devices there is `/dev/video0`, `/dev/video`, etc.

For terminals there are `/dev/tty1`, `/dev/tty2`, etc.

For storage devices there are `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc.

There used to be a `/dev/dsp` for the sound device.  However, at present, it doesn't exist.

Can someone tell me of sound device equivalent for the purpose of interfacing to the raw device?

I have spent a lot of time studying the content of the `/dev` subdirectory.  I can't identify an item that would represent the sound device, or which device to try to connect to.

The **arecord** command shows these sound devices available:

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889A Analog [ALC889A Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 2: ALC889A Alt Analog [ALC889A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 2: HDMI [USB Capture HDMI], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: C525 [HD Webcam C525], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Is there a way to interpret this information and use it to capture audio from any or all of those devices.

What can I substitute from other commands for using the ffmpeg commands such as these commands for the capture?

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i /dev/dsp out.wav
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:2 -t 30 out.wav
```

The `arecord -l` output without `pavucontrol` running:

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889A Analog [ALC889A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 2: ALC889A Alt Analog [ALC889A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 2: HDMI [USB Capture HDMI], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: C525 [HD Webcam C525], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

### Update based on information from the comments

**This command produces a 30 second file with sound coming from my USB HDMI capture card:**

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:2 -t 30 out.wav
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:2':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1513743504.091042, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'out.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s16le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    5621kB time=00:00:30.00 bitrate=1535.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:5621kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.001355%
```

**This command produces the following error when trying to capture sound from my webcam mic:**
(The errors are the last two lines of output.)

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:3 -t 30 out.wav
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[alsa @ 0x17c7f80] cannot set channel count to 2 (Invalid argument)
hw:3: Input/output error
```

**This command (using the output from `arecord -L` of [this anwer](https://askubuntu.com/a/986189/29012), works without errors:**

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i plughw:CARD=C525,DEV=0 -t 30 out.wav
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'plughw:CARD=C525,DEV=0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1513743836.271555, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'out.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 pcm_s16le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    5625kB time=00:00:30.00 bitrate=1536.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:5625kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.001354%
```

Other variations of the command to try to get sound from the webcam included (from [nik gnomic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985037/where-is-the-audio-device-in-ubuntu-16-04lts?noredirect=1#comment1591503_985037)'s comment):

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:3,0 -t 30 out.wav
```

Comment: Have you checked  `/proc/asound/devices`?

Comment: Yes.  I see a list of things... some of them resemble some of the `arecord` output.  However the problem is that I don't know how to interpret it into the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: With `arecord -L` (capital L) you will see a list of the configured devices. If using PulseAudio, the "default" device will usually be PA; so `ffmpeg -f alsa -i default` will record from the device set in PulseAudio. Otherwise, you should use the command as you suggested: `ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:3 ...` (hw:3 means card #3, as shown with arecord -l).

Comment: @ridgy I thought I had tried all variations of the command.  The resulting fine didn't have any sound.  There weren't any errors, just no sound in the file.  I'll go over them again very carefully.  I really expected the `default` option you included would have produced a file with sound, but it didn't.  I'll give an update if I experience any success.  By the way, I understand what the `default` option should be doing.  I'm hoping to be able to be able to choose a specific device from the number of devices and leave the default for other applications.

Comment: maybe the pacmd list can help https://superuser.com/a/1158969/169112

Comment: @Katu `pacmd list` has 1356 lines.  Is there a filter you want me to apply and post the results?  By the way, do you have a USB Webcam?  Is there a `ffmpeg` command that you can use that works?  If it works, what command did you type in to get the specs to supply for the audio device?

Comment: @ridgy The `ffmpeg -f alsa -i default output.wav` produces sound.  I had used that variation along with `ffmpeg -f pulse -i default output.wav` and many more that I had found doing my 48 hour research.  Also I had made a number of changes from my different devices for which was the default.  So at present installing `pavucontrol` and setting a default is a workaround.  Figuring out how to use the commandline to specify among the multiple devices installed is the objective.  The default will change, but the script will always point to the right hardware device.

Comment: @L.D.James You will find a grep filter in the link provided. I haven't tried ffmpeg myself, I just thought that it could be  a good place for you to start.

Comment: @Katu Thanks.  I had visited those pages during the 72 hours before posting my message.  I really appreciate the input.  I performed lots of experiments with various options.  Some of them probably work based on what might be installed by default, but I couldn't figure it out.  Also I was hoping to have input for whats built into Ubuntu by default.

Comment: your ffmpeg command would need to be "hw:2,0" to specify the capture sub-device.
but arecord shows Card 2 subdevices: 0/1 - this means there are zero devices available for ALSA recording (probably in use by Pulseaudio?)

Comment: @nikgnomic Thanks for the input.  I can't understand where the `2,0` in hw:**2,0** comes from.  The Web Camera is lasted as `card 3:`.  If I can understand the specification, then it would elimenate having to experiement to get the correct device.  I'd just test the device, and if there's failure, it would be clear that it's being used by something else, and I'll know what I search for... and in your reference, the device might be used by Pulseaudio.

Comment: @nikgnomic By the way, I have a working solution of which I'll post as an answer once I have it clearly defined where it would be extremely simple and easy for any novice to follow.   If your comment were clear to me and I would suggest your posting it as an answer to which I would accept.

Comment: @L D James - I used hw:2,0 based on your ffmpeg command.
If you want capture from card 3 webcam, it would be hw:3,0
command needs device to be available for capture - subdevices: 1/1

Comment: @nikgnomic Thanks for the input on this question.  I don't understand how this works.  It's not consistent for me.  I'm able to use the output of `arecord -L`, which I described the usage in this question:
 https://askubuntu.com/a/986189/29012 .  However, I don't understand how to use the output of the lowercase `arecord -l` variation, which appears to be cleaner and simpler.  The `ffmpeg` command included in this question was something that I found on the internet, as an example explaining the usage... the lack of understanding it is the purpose of the question. (continued)...

Comment: ...the output of my `arecord -l` changes from time to time and between boots.  I'll post an update in the question of how it's looking now.  I always get an error when I try to use `hw:3` or any variation that includes having the `3` in it.  `hw:2` usually doesn't get errors, even though sometimes it doesn't give sound.  Using the output from `arecord -L` always work every time.  Previously I had pavucontrol` loaded to help find the devices.  So you were right about there possibly being a conflict with PulseAudio usage.

Comment: Have you tried `ffmpeg -sources` instead of hw for input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there may be other tools to provide the audio device, **Arecord** is provided in Ubuntu 16.04 by default.

The command to list the available sound devices is (the command and output in my case follows):

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC889A Analog [ALC889A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 2: ALC889A Alt Analog [ALC889A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 2/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
card 2: C525 [HD Webcam C525], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Microphone [Yeti Stereo Microphone], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 4: HDMI [USB Capture HDMI], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

In this case the Webcam audio is the hardware device `Card 2`.  The device specification for **ffmpeg** in this case is `hw:2`.

The problem in the question, by the error output, is in the **ffmpeg** capture program's default.  It's generating the error `cannot set channel count to 2 (Invalid argument)` because the **Webcam** is apparently using audio channel 1 for it's capture, while the capture application, **ffmpeg** is apparently trying to capture from audio channel 2 (which is ffmpeg's default capture channel).

Capturing audio from the Webcam work from the GUI applications because they apparently have some catching mechanism to identify the available audio channel for the input and pulling from that channel.

**Specify the capture channel for ffmpeg**

To specify the capture channel for the ffmpeg app, use the `-ac [channel #]` before the `-i` argument.

For the command in the question make this change:

**Change From:**

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:2 -t 30 out.wav
```

**Change to:**

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:2 -t 30 out.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have found your working solution with:

`ffmpeg -f alsa -i plughw:CARD=C525,DEV=0 -t 30 out.wav`

`hw:CARD=C525,DEV=0` is better option than using `hw:3,0`
USB devices *might* be assigned a different card number
card name avoids possible error if device number changes

`plughw:` is better option than `hw:`
plughw deals with any samplerate conversion

Comment: Yes.  I have that as a working solution with formatting details to make it easy for usage.  I was hoping you would have input on how to use your suggested `hw:` variation.